# Navigate between different stacks

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to navigate from one stack to another in react native. From my `LoginStack`, how can I navigate to the `ReleaseDetail` screen of the `HomeStack`? Instead of opening the modal of `ReleaseDetail` in `LoginStack`, I want to navigate to the screen `ReleaseDetail` of the `HomeStack`.

I'm using `react-native-navigation` v3. I tried using NavigationActions to go to the home stack but when it tries to navigate I get a `no-op` error saying the component was unmounted.

LoginStack.js:

```
    onDetailButtonPress={() => {
        const { selectedReleaseId } = this.props.playQueue
        this.props.navigation.navigate(
          NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: 'HomeStackView',
            params: { releaseId: selectedReleaseId },
            action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ReleaseDetail' })
          })
        )
        )
    }}
```

Router.js:

```
export const appContainer = createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
            SignedOutStack: SignedOutStack,
            LoggedInStackView: LoggedInStack,
            HomeStackView: HomeStack,
            Onboard: OnboardStack
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
        }
    )
)
```

HomeStack.js:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen
        },
        Settings: {
            screen: SettingsScreen
        },
        ReleaseDetail: {
            screen: ReleaseInfoContainerScreen
        },
        SettingOnboard: {
            screen: OnboardStack
        }
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none'
    }
)
```

LoginStack.js:

```
export const LoggedInStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        TabNavigator: {
            screen: connectedLoggedInTabContainerView,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null
            }
        },
        SelectPlayList: {
            screen: props => (
                <SelectPlayListScreen
                    {...props}
                    type={PlaylistScreenType.add}
                />
            ),
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: null
            })
        },
        ReleaseDetail: {
            screen: props => (
                <ReleaseInfoContainerScreen {...props} modal={true}/>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        headerMode: 'none'
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the components (i.e. the page you are navigating to and the one you are navigating from) with “withNavigation”

For example
If you want to navigate from PlayerScreen to HomeScreen
When exporting the PlayerScreen and HomeScreen,

`import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'`
Then when exporting the components use

`export default withNavigation(PlayerScreen)`

`export default withNavigation(HomeScreen)`

Then use the `NavigationActions`

I hope this is helpful

Comment: The problem I'm having is that the button to trigger navigation is in the LoginStack.js file so I can't wrap it with `withNavigation`

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log to check the output to see if you have navigation as the prop.

In LoginStack.js add a `console.log("PROPS", this.props)`, then check the result to see if it's linked to navigation.